# Confusion Between Sharepoint and .Net(asp,mvc,mvvm silverlight)

Tags: .net, sharepoint

hey i am little bit confuse which is better in terms of today's scenarios SharePoint or .Net.

Please tell me which is best and how ?????? 
can anyone evaluate the basic difference between both these technologies 
there is a lot of confusion....

Comment: What do you want to do with SharePoint or .NET?

Comment: Actually i got a job in a company on the basics of my C#,Asp.net knowledge and now they want that i worked in SharePoint .So I am confuse that in which plateform my future will became more bright....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@viipiin There is a lot of difference between the two. To start with .Net is a framework created by Microsoft. This includes all the libraries and files you would need to create an application using C#/ VB (you can also throw in Lightswitch if you want). SharePoint is an enterprise software by Microsoft. There are however scopes for development on SharePoint as well. Hope this clears the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Giving more insight to Akshay's answer.

Sharepoint is a platform (Services & applications) built on top of .Net Framework.

[.Net Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) is:

> .NET Framework (pronounced dot net) is a software framework developed
>   by Microsoft that runs primarily on Microsoft Windows. It includes a
>   large class library known as Framework Class Library (FCL) and
>   provides language interoperability (each language can use code written
>   in other languages) across several programming languages. Programs
>   written for .NET Framework execute in a software environment (as
>   contrasted to hardware environment), known as Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR), an application virtual machine that provides services such as
>   security, memory management, and exception handling. FCL and CLR
>   together constitute .NET Framework.